# How can I set a make variable to a target dependent value?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I'm not a make expert so apologies if this is a silly question. I would like to set a make variable as part of a target so in target1 its value is -DPARENT and in target2 -DCHILD. I have some generic rules that are obeyed when the dependencies of these targets are checked and I need those defines set appropriately to be passed to gcc.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(XML)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(XML_BUILD_TYPE) -c -o $@  $<

$(PROD)/Parent: \
        somehow set XML_BUILD_TYPE = -DPARENT here \
        $(XML)/Xml.h \
        $(TOOLS_OBJS) \
        $(XML_PARENT_OBJECTS) \
        $(XML_INPUTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(TOOLS_OBJS) $(XML_PARENT_OBJECTS) -rdynamic $(JSON_LIB) $(CURL_LIB) $(LIBS) -lssl -lidn

$(PROD)/Child: \
        somehow set XML_BUILD_TYPE = -DCHILD here \
        $(XML)/Xmlr.h \
        $(TOOLS_OBJS) \
        $(XML_CHILD_OBJECTS) \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $(OBJ)/LinkDate.o  $(TOOLS)/LinkDate.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $(TOOLS_OBJS) $(XML_CHILD_OBJECTS) -rdynamic $(OBJ)/LinkDate.o $(JSON_LIB) $(CURL_LIB) $(LIBS) -lssl -lidn
```

I have tried `$(eval XML_BUILD_TYPE := -DCHILD)` only to find make evaluates all the evals when it reads the makefile resulting in whatever was last being set always. I am sure it must be possible to do this but blowed if I can find out how.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: PS: `$(XML_CHILD_OBJECTS)` is a list of objects needed for the build. Some are in common for the parent and child but I want to `#ifdef` child specific parts out of the parent build and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You just put the variable before your make target:

```
$(PROD)/Parent: XML_BUILD_TYPE = -DPARENT
$(PROD)/Parent: \
        $(XML)/Xml.h \
        $(TOOLS_OBJS) \
        $(XML_PARENT_OBJECTS) \
        $(XML_INPUTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(TOOLS_OBJS) $(XML_PARENT_OBJECTS) -rdynamic $(JSON_LIB) $(CURL_LIB) $(LIBS) -lssl -lidn

$(PROD)/Child: XML_BUILD_TYPE = -DCHILD
$(PROD)/Child: \
        $(XML)/Xmlr.h \
        $(TOOLS_OBJS) \
        $(XML_CHILD_OBJECTS) \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $(OBJ)/LinkDate.o  $(TOOLS)/LinkDate.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $(TOOLS_OBJS) $(XML_CHILD_OBJECTS) -rdynamic $(OBJ)/LinkDate.o $(JSON_LIB) $(CURL_LIB) $(LIBS) -lssl -lidn
```

You can have as many as you want of those:

```
$(PROD)/Parent: XML_BUILD_TYPE = -DPARENT
$(PROD)/Parent: ANOTHERVAR = -DSOMETHING
$(PROD)/Parent: $(XML)/Xml.h $(TOOLS_OBJS) $(XML_PARENT_OBJECTS) $(XML_INPUTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(TOOLS_OBJS) $(XML_PARENT_OBJECTS) -rdynamic $(JSON_LIB) $(CURL_LIB) $(LIBS) -lssl -lidn
```

Comment: I tried that and was told 'multiple targets found, using the last one'. I also got told 'you are running commands before setting dependencies'. Make was mean to me over that!

Comment: Sergey's answer is correct.  If it didn't work then you typed it in wrong, or else you're using a very old version of GNU make.  Run `make --version`; what do you get?  Also make won't print those errors (although it will print something similar).  It's helpful if you cut and paste the exact error rather than paraphrasing; sometimes minor differences mean a lot.  If you still can't get it to work, update your question with a cut/paste of the exact makefile you tried.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a good way that I'm not aware of, but until someone posts it... here's how I've solved this sort of problem before.

```
$(PROD)/Parent:
        make XML_BUILD_TYPE=-DPARENT Parent_Build

Parent_Build:
        # put in build steps for the parent; $(XML_BUILD_TYPE) is already set
```

For this strategy, you would never call `make Parent_Build from the command line yourself; you simply allow make to call it internally as it knows to set the needed variable(s).

Of course, you can extend this for multiple targets and multiple variables as needed.

Comment: Recursion's the way to go, eh? Thanks for that, it works a treat!

Comment: Recursion is _a_ way to go.  It's conceptually simple and will likely work fine for simple situations like this.  It can even sometimes be preferred.  But when your make environment gets complex, recursion has a lot of downsides as well.